# looking for button commands for actionscript 3.0

Tags: flash, actionscript, button, flash-cs5

Im new at actionscript 3.0 and am currently doing a flash presentation. It is all completed except for the buttons, I have no idea how to use actionscript 3.0. I have a lot of buttons but all i need is the commands to make the button (when clicked on) go to another scene and also replay the scene it is on.

Thanks

Comment: @user729786 are you using the document class or the timeline?

Answer (score 3):

If you have a button on stage, let's say called `button0`, then:

```
button0.addEventListener("click", button0Clicked);

function button0Clicked(evt:*):void
{
     //do whatever you want to do here
}
```

There are some other events, just change click to `mouseDown`, `mouseUp`, `doubleClick`, `mouseOver`, `mouseOut`. I think these types speak for themselves.

If you use doubleclick, you have to set `doubleClickEnabled` to `true`:

```
button0.doubleClickEnabled = true;
```

Also really useful to know:

```
button0.buttonMode = true;
button0.useHandCursor = true;
```

If button0 is not a Button instance, but a MovieClip instance and you want the mouse to turn into a "hand" when the mouse is over the button.

I hope this helps you to get closer to your goal.

Answer (score 0):

```
 import flash.events.MouseEvent;
 //use stop in the begin to avoid the repeat frames again
 stop();

//here i have play button is play_mc if it click then it goes to the 
 function GameStart

mc.play_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, GameStart);
mc.play_mc.useHandCursor = true;
mc.play_mc.buttonMode = true;

function GameStart(event:MouseEvent):void
{
 //gotoAndPlay by using to go to the frame Gameplay is the frame name it 
   goes to that frame

   gotoAndPlay("GamePlay");
}
```

If you want to know more go here and learn http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/accessible_animated_preso.html